# Как удалить из текста все слова заданной длины?

Tags: строки, java

Привет, профессиональным коде рам. У меня к Вам вопрос. Помогите составить или описать пример кода программы.

Нужно удалить из текста все слова заданной длины (начинающийся на гласную букву). Текст любой.

Comment: "Кодер" звучит немного оскорбительно :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код ниже удалит из строки все слова длиной 5 символов, используя регулярные выражения:

```
to = from.replaceAll("\\b\\w{5,5}\\b", "");
```

Аналогично можно составить регулярку с учетом гласных букв.